# Sales invoice form

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am designing a sales invoice form. I am able to pull data from MySQL for selection.

When it comes to items, the number of items is variable. Sometimes, it's 3 items and sometimes, it's 20.

How do I add rows and delete rows based on user's input for the no of rows required (all these rows will be select drop downs pulled from MySQL)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. Could you add some more details please?

Comment: Apart from more detail, please add the structure of your database and code you have so far. It's hard to guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something you can do with combination of PHP & Jquery & Ajax.

```
<script>
$('select[name=items]').change(function () {
// If selected value is bigger than 0
if ($(this).val() > 0 ) {  
   $.post("get-items.php", {itemval: $(this).val()}, function(data) {
      //$('#items').fadeIn('slow'); // Remove the beginning // to use this effect.
      $('#items').html(data);
   });
}

});
</script>
```

Now the important thing here is;

- Your select box name is **items**
- When the items select box value will change (and if it is bigger than 0), it will send the value to get-items.php.
- get-items.php must echo with html in it (if you want to). For example:

  You want to list the data with some html elements;

  ```
  <ul>
  <li>First Item</li>
  <li>Second Item</li>
  <li>Third Item</li>
  </ul>
  ```

Your get-items.php should output (echo) like this in order to use it in your page (imagine it like include. Whatever you will echo out, it will include with all html elements in it to the page where you want to use it.

- Once your get-items.php will return some output, the code will gather the output and add the response to the element which has items id. For example;

  ```
  <div id="items"></div>
  ```
- You can gather posted value in get-items.php;

  ```
  $itemValue = $_POST['itemval'];
  ```

Once you can gather information about item value (show, don't show, show limited etc.. it is your decision) with PHP, after that it is your decision to what to echo out to browser.

I hope I understood you correctly and I hope this helps.

**EDIT**

After your comment, about gathering more information depending on user selection (it can be 1 or more) so I believe easiest way to go with will be following;

We will use Json with Jquery.

```
$.getJSON('get-product-info.php', function(data) {
    // Create an array
    var productSetup = [];
    // Loop and assign Json (returned value) to our new setup array
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        productSetup[key] = val;
        // Add values to html elements and other actions here.
    });
});
```

What we did here is quite simple. We gathered information about product(s) from **get-product-info.php** with help of Jquery & Json. We created productSetup jquery array and assigned returned values from **get-product-info.php**

When you gather data from get-product-info.php, for us to make our life easier we will use Json to be able to translate data from PHP to Jquery.

**get-product-info.php** Important information

1. After you do your query, create a new Array to return results as an array.
2. Gathered new results array must be encoded with json and echo it out so Jquery could capture it.

**Example**

```
<?php
#Assuming $data is your new results array
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

We use Json to transfer data easily from one language to another. In the begging of my answer, I already gave you a code to send information. When user makes more choices just send them to your php script, and gather the returned results via Json to alter html elements in your page.

Please check [**PHP json_encode user manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [**PHP json_decode user manual**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for more information.

I hope this helps

Comment: thanks for the response. i am also seeking advise on how to display the product name from the database based in the selection of product id by user. and then adding other fields such as unit price,total amount, etc.

Comment: Well then we need to add 4th thing. Json.

Comment: Edited my answer. Please check.